# How do I determine whether ASP.NET 3.5 is installed on Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net, iis

I hate to ask a question that seems like it should be easy to find the answer to on the web, however I am unable to find a straightforward answer anywhere as to how to check what version of ASP.NET is installed on my Windows Server 2008 r2. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Kind regards, Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read registry key, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components\` as documented in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components

As you use IIS 7, its "ASP.NET" feature matches ASP.NET 3.5 you are looking for. If you want to check ASP.NET 4.x, then this approach won't work.

Generally speaking, the ASP.NET component in IIS wraps over `aspnet_regiis` command line tool to register ASP.NET bits on IIS (ISAPI and so on). Microsoft designed it this way so it felt more natural. However, it turns out to be a disaster later, as .NET Framework new releases can easily break the design.

For example, on IIS 7 if you use ASP.NET 4.x then you have to manually run `aspnet_regiis` from .NET Framework 4.x installation folder, as there is not ASP.NET 4.x component on IIS 7.

Comment: thank you for your response. I followed the path to the registry key that you gave and I see that ASPNET is in fact in Components, however, I don't understand how that matches ASP.NET 3.5? I followed the link to docs.microsoft... and I don't see anything that positively identifies it as 3.5. Couldn't it be another version such as ASP.NET 4.x, etc.? Please clarify. :)

Comment: Added some ASP.NET 4.x info.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework
```

and check if there is v3.5 folder